# MAtrix always has the same elements when is stored in a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I want to write a code to reproduces yahtee game and I started creating a matrix and then store the dice roll into the every line of the matrix into a list, what happens is all the element in every matrix persists to be the same when I ask to print the matrix or the list I want to show every matrix with the dice rolls showing a diferent values

CODE:

```
matriz <- matrix(1:5, nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
listas <- list()

rolar <- function() {
  dados <- 1:6
  dados <- replicate(1, sample(dados, size = 1,replace = TRUE))
  return(dados)
}

for (i in 1:10) {
  matriz[i, ] <- rolar()
  listas[[i]] <- matriz
  print(listas[i])
}

str(listas)
```

Comment: Do you want all possible permutations of the numbers 1 to 6?

Comment: I think the issue is coming from your call to `replicate` / `sample`. Try reading the help file for `sample` and I don't think `replicate` is necessary. You would probably be fine with something like `sample(dados, 5, replace = TRUE)`.

Comment: Hello Friend thanks for coment, I tried but the Str(listas) the command will returned the same element for every matrix another sugestion ? 
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 5 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 5 1 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 5 1 6 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 5 1 6 2 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 5 1 6 2 1 3 4 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 5 1 6 2 1 2 4 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 5 1 6 2 1 2 5 5 ...
 $ : int [1:10, 1:5] 4 2 5 1 6 2 1 2 5 5 ...

Comment: I want randomic results about 1:6 in every line of the Matrix for all Marix not the same results

Answer (score 1):

As usual, I'm likely completely wrong, but in yathee I tend to be praying that some combination of 5 dice are produced, and maybe that's not how I should look at it, but none the less, shake, shake:

```
set.seed(1234) # as we are using sample
matriz <-matrix(1:5,nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
rolar <- function() {
  dados <- 1:6
  dados <- sample(dados, size = 5, replace = TRUE)
}

for (i in 1:10) {
  matriz[i, ] = rolar()
  print(matriz[i, ])[i]
  }
[1] 4 2 4 2 2
[1] 1 4 6 2 3
[1] 5 6 1 5 3
[1] 6 3 3 2 2
[1] 5 1 6 5 4
[1] 6 3 3 4 1
[1] 1 2 5 4 4
[1] 6 3 6 1 2
[1] 3 6 2 1 6
[1] 6 6 6 5 5
```

And these are my first ten rolls; but, it doesn't matter, my wife will still beat me.(actually these are my second round of ten rolls, but she'll still beat me.)

Comment: And, what were her rolls? Is she invincible?